# How do I link the methods to the gui?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to create a football management system that will allow the user to input data into the gui and then it will save to a database. I have the methods, such as "getName" as shown in the code below and I am unsure how to link that to my gui. I have included the code for my methods and the a link to an image of my gui to allow you to see what it looks like as the code is long. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Player {

    private int id;
    private String forename;
    private String surname;
    private Date dob;
    private String position;
    private int number;
    private int teamid;

    public int getID() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setID(int i) {
    id = i;
    }
}
```

[image: Image of the gui]

Comment: (A) Way too much code. Post the briefest example possible. (B) By the way, the troublesome `Date` class is replaced by `java.time.Instant` in modern Java.

Comment: As an aside, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others. Also, that window should be a modal JDialog and not a JFrame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the look of it you need to apply a **ActionPerformed** event for your **Add** Button (off the hip):

```
// ADD Button.
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    Player player = new Player();

    // Player ID  
    String id = textPlayerID.getText();
    if (!id.equals("")) {
        // Make sure a numerical value was supplied.
        if (id.matches("\\d+")) {
            player.setID(Integer.parseInt(id);
        }
    }

    // Player First Name
    String firstName = textForename.getText();
    if (!firstName.equals("")) {
        player.setForename(firstName);
    }

    // Player Last Name
    String LastName = textSurname.getText();
    if (!lastName.equals("")) {
        player.setSurname(lastName);
    }


    // Player Date Of Birth
    String dob = textDOB.getText();
    if (!dob.equals("")) {
        // You should add code here to 'validate' the fact that
        // a valid date was supplied within the JTextField.

        // Format the date desired.
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        // Convert String date to a Date data Type. 
        Date dateOfBirth = formatter.parse(dob);
        player.setDOB(dateOfBirth);
    }

    // Player Position
    String position = textPosition.getText();
    if (!position.equals("")) {
        player.setPosition(position);
    }

    // Player Number  
    String number = textNumber.getText();
    if (!number.equals("")) {
        // Make sure a numerical value was supplied.
        if (id.matches("\\d+")) {
            player.setNumber(Integer.parseInt(number);
        }
    }

    // Player Team ID  
    String teamID = textTeamID.getText();
    if (!teamID.equals("")) {
        // Make sure a numerical value was supplied.
        if (id.matches("\\d+")) {
            player.setTeamID(Integer.parseInt(teamID);
        }
    }

    // Create and call a method to add the contents 
    // of the player object into database. If the
    // player already exists within the database then
    // use the UPDATE sql statement. If the player
    // does not exist within the databse then use the 
    // INSERT INTO sql statement.
    addToDatabase(player);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With "link to the GUI" I suppose you mean call those methods when an event occurs in the GUI.

You can do that by first having **an instance of your Player-class** in your GUI-class and then call those methods in the appropriate event-handlers that are so conveniently but so unorganized created by NetBeans (those somethingActionPerformed methods).

Please be more specific on what you're trying to do if I haven't explained it enough for you and please [name your GUI components](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/learn/logic.html) for more clarity in your code.

Comment: Sorry I am really basic on Java so what do you mean by an instance of the class?

Comment: Player **player** = new Player();